# Force Box2D object to stay still over a rotating object

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm trying to use Box2D in my game but I have a problem with one particular player movement. I have two different objects. The first one is a rectangle with fixed rotation that represent the player. The other one is an octagonal wheel that can rotate and moves from right to left and viceversa.

When the player is over the wheel the user can swipe to let the player run over the wheel. In that moment the wheel start to rotate and the player object should stay over the wheel while running. The problem is that the friction makes the player fall. I tried to remove the friction of the player and reset the contact friction while running but still fall because the linear velocity of the player while the wheel is moving from side to side.

My last attempt to solve it was use setLinearVelocity(0, 0) over both bodies at the beginning of the run movement but doesn't work very well...

So the question is, how can I force a Box2D object to stay over the wheel while this one is rotating and moving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is faking it..... Just keep on resetting the position to intial position....
Other way is to create an invisible weld joint of the player to some other point.
I hope it helps